# Visual Studio 2008: Conversion wizard every time I open the project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, conversion-wizard

I've tried to convert a VS2008 solution to VS2010, but it didn't really work. So I wanted to change the solution back to VS2008.

I've reverted all the files to their original state (with subversion) and it seems to work well, but every time I open the project the conversion wizard is "updating" my solution to VS2008, which is annoying.

Other than that everything works fine.

Any ideas how to open it without the wizard showing up every time ?

---

Edit:

I've checked out another copy of the project - and this seems to work fine. "Dialecticus" wrote me to delete all ncb, opt and user files. I just had .user files but deleting them didn't help. After that I've deleted the working copy and checked out another version - now it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some of the unversioned files is causing this behavior. Checkout another copy of repository and see if the problem occurs. Usual suspect files: .ncb, .suo, .user.

Comment: Deleting .vssscc file did the trick for me. Prior to deleting this file, opening the solution would repeatedly open the migration wizard, will show the project as loaded in the solution explorer, but the project would become unavailable as soon as the wizard closed. I made all the files in solution folder writeable and deleted the .vssscc file. The project loaded fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Office Tools -> Project Upgrade

Try clearing the option Always upgrade to the installed version of Office.

Comment: try going to tools -> import export in visual studio and reset settings, see if that helps